# Pointer notation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I don't find the theory of pointers particularly troublesome, but I am occasionally flummoxed by some of the notation. In the following example, can someone explain how the line `p = (int*) a` works. The explanation I have of the code suggests that this line simply stores the address of the first element of the first array in the pointer p, such that `printf("%u", *p)`yields `5`. If this is the case is this line simply a more indirect way of writing `p = a[0]`?

```
int main()
{
    int a[][4] = {
        5, 7, 5, 9,
        4, 6, 3, 1,
        2, 9, 0, 6
        };



    int *p; // create an integer pointer
    int (*q)[4]; // create a pointer to a four-element integer array

    p = (int*)a; // ?
    q = a;


    printf("%u %u\n", p, q);
    p++;
    q++;
    printf("%u %u\n", p, q);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `a`, when used in value context, will indeed evaluate to the "address of the first element of the array `a`" - address of `a[0]` - as you correctly understood it.

However, note that array `a` is actually what we call a *2D* array. It is an *array of arrays*. The first element of array `a` is by itself an array: an array of type `int [4]`. So, taking the above into account, expression `a`, when used in value context, is equivalent to expression `&a[0]`, which is a pointer of type `int (*)[4]` and which conceptually points to the *entire* 1D array `a[0]`.

For this reason, an attempt to do

```
p = a;
```

would result in a diagnostic message from the compiler. It is illegal to assign an `int (*)[4]` value to a `int *` pointer object. These types are not compatible. In order to suppress this diagnostic message the code in question uses an explicit cast

```
p = (int *) a;
```

This forcefully shoves the aforementioned `int (*)[4]` pointer value into `p`. In a typical implementation this preserves the numerical value of the original pointer, only performing a conceptual type conversion.

An attempt to access the value of `*p` will typically produce the value of `a[0][0]` simply because *numerically* the address of the entire `a` is the same as the address of `a[0]` and is the same as the address of `a[0][0]`. The code above exploits this numerical identity, while using the explicit cast to work around the type incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer. Although I was aware that I was working with a 2-D array, I hadn't appreciated that the pointer &a[0] was a pointer to an [array of ints] rather than a simple [int] pointer. I also missed the fact there was some casting going on. This was a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 7):

> The explanation I have of the code suggests that this line simply stores the address of the first element of the first array in the pointer p

Correct.

> If this is the case is this line simply a more indirect way of writing `p = a[0]`?

No, it isn't. "this line simply stores **the address** of the first element" - it's rather *similar to*

```
p = &a[0];
```

But the above statement is not entirely correct, since `&a[0]` is of type `int (*)[4]`. The correct assignment without a cast could be something like

```
p = &a[0][0];
```

Play around with compiling various declarations using with `-Wall` turned on and google the occasional errors/warnings :)

Comment: @ruakh: nah, the 2d-indexing goes one below - I've expanded the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on H2CO3's answer, remember that in most contexts an expression of *array* type will be converted to an expression of *pointer* type, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The type of the expression `a` is "3-element array of 4-element array of `int`".  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, `a` will be *converted* to an expression of type "pointer to 4-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[4]`), and its value will be the address of `a[0]`.  The problem is that a value of type `int (*)[4]` cannot be assigned to a variable of type `int *`; the types are not *compatible*, so we need to cast the result of the expression `a` to `int *`.

This works because the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array are the same - the expressions `a`, `&a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` all yield the same *value*, they just have different *types* (`int (*)[4]`, `int (*)[4][4]`, `int *`, `int (*)[4]`, and `int *`, respectively).

Comment: Thanks also. You're quite correct; the difference between a pointer of type int (*)[4] and of type int * was news to me, and central to my failure to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Almost. It's similar to writing `p = &a[0][0]`.

Answer (score -2):

`a` is an array `3` of array `4` of `int`.

The value of `a` is a pointer to an array `4` of `int`. The value of this pointer is the address of the beginning of the array.

`(int *) a` converts the pointer to a pointer to `int`. The value does not change but the type is different.

Note that to print a pointer value, the correct specification is `p`.

Comment: "The value of a is a pointer to" No. The value of `a` is an array.

Comment: @newacct Common terminology misunderstanding. `a` is an array (read my first line). Now the *value* of an array is a pointer to its first element. The value of an object is what it *evaluates* to. For arrays there are the exceptions of the operators that do not evaluate their operand (`&` and `sizeof`) and the string literal initializer for a character array.

Comment: No. The type of the expression `a` is an array type. Hence, its value is an array value. An array value can be implicitly converted into a pointer value when it is used in some contexts. That does not mean they are the same. If you take the address of an array value, you get a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @newacct C does not have array values. The value of an array is con verted to a pointer type. `&` of an array operand is a pointer to an array and not a pointer to a pointer because the array operand of `&` operator is not evaluated. I suggest you some good reading regarding values and objects: the excellent "The Rule" by Chris Torek: http://web.torek.net/torek/c/expr.html#therule

Comment: No, it is you who don't understand what a value is. The type of an expression is defined to be the type of the value that it evaluates to.

Comment: Hrmpf. I think Torek's terminology has "What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described as the ‘‘value of an expression’’" going for it. But it's not quite the same. Better stick to "(Except ...) an expression of type array of T is converted to an expression of type pointer to T".